# spring mvc + mybatis + mysql5.7 save less time for 8 hours

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, mybatis

spring mvc + mybatis + mysql 5.7 + jdk8
I use mysql 5.7 for save json data.
I use jdk8 time API `LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();` to get datetime and save to database.
But I fund the result of database are less time for about 8 hours.
**My treatment process**
1、Code problems, debug it, and I find the time in the object is right before it save to the database.
2、System time zone problem, the investigation of the local computer system, server system, database system and other computer systems, time zones are all East eight district no problem. (I am Chinese)
3、View console print SQL

```
DEBUG [ 2017-08-23 12:42:35 970 ]: org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.debug(BaseJdbcLogger.java:145) - ==>  Preparing: insert into log_user_operation (pk_id, user_code, user_name, login_ip, url, operation_type, operation_content, remark, create_time) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
DEBUG [ 2017-08-23 12:42:36 005 ]: org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.debug(BaseJdbcLogger.java:145) - ==> Parameters: null, admin(String), Admin(String), 127.0.0.1(String), http://localhost:8080/bi/login-check(String), SELECT(String), 用户登录(String), (String), 2017-08-23 12:42:32.9(Timestamp)
DEBUG [ 2017-08-23 12:42:36 016 ]: org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.debug(BaseJdbcLogger.java:145) - <==    Updates: 1
DEBUG [ 2017-08-23 12:42:36 020 ]: org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.debug(BaseJdbcLogger.java:145) - ==>  Preparing: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() 
DEBUG [ 2017-08-23 12:42:36 021 ]: org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.debug(BaseJdbcLogger.java:145) - ==> Parameters: 
TRACE [ 2017-08-23 12:42:36 039 ]: org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.trace(BaseJdbcLogger.java:151) - <==    Columns: LAST_INSERT_ID()
TRACE [ 2017-08-23 12:42:36 039 ]: org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.trace(BaseJdbcLogger.java:151) - <==        Row: 47
DEBUG [ 2017-08-23 12:42:36 042 ]: org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.debug(BaseJdbcLogger.java:145) - <==      Total: 1
DEBUG [ 2017-08-23 12:42:36 047 ]: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils.closeSqlSession(SqlSessionUtils.java:193) - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@516c8654]
DEBUG [ 2017-08-23 12:42:36 048 ]: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doReleaseConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:332) - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

I feel that everything is OK, but the database save is wrong.
[the test result of right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3nxT.png)

Comment: so `LocalDateTime.now()` gives you the correct time?

Comment: @JackFlamp Yes, and the sql is right, too.  But when I see the mysql database, it is wrong.

Comment: Sounds like the error is in the Database. Check the settings for the time column in your table

Answer (score 0):

The problem that has been bothering for two days is finally settled this evening.
This is due to the URL specification of the new MySQL drive package:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ss?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=true&serverTimezone=UTC&nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true
```

Modify `serverTimezone=UTC` to `serverTimezone=Hongkong` can solve the problem successfully。